# volumes value ' do not match any of the regexes: u'^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$' - Error in elasticsearch docker-compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

### Trying to start elastic search cluster using docker-compose given [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html)

- I am not sure what is the issue here. I am running this docker-compose.yaml file in ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Tried find this error online but no help.

#### docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
##############################################################################################
# LINKS - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html
##############################################################################################
version: "2.2"
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.8.0
    container_name: es01_dev
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name="es-docker-cluster"
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - /data/var/lib/elasticsearch-server_01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
#      - /data/var/elasticsearch-server-backup:/var/elasticsearch-backup
#      - /opt/elasticsearch-server/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.8.0
    container_name: es02_dev
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name="es-docker-cluster"
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - /data/var/lib/elasticsearch-server_02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
#      - /data/var/elasticsearch-server-backup:/var/elasticsearch-backup
#      - /opt/elasticsearch-server/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    networks:
      - elastic
  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.8.0
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name="es-docker-cluster"
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock:=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - /data/var/lib/elasticsearch-server_03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
#      - /data/var/elasticsearch-server-backup:/var/elasticsearch-backup
#      - /opt/elasticsearch-server/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  /data/var/lib/elasticsearch-server_01:
    driver: local
  /data/var/lib/elasticsearch-server_02:
    driver: local
  /data/var/lib/elasticsearch-server_03:
    driver: local
networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

#### But docker-compose up given me this error

```sh
visionary@instance-2:/opt/elasticsearch-server$ docker-compose up
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
volumes value '/data/var/lib/elasticsearch-server_01', '/data/var/lib/elasticsearch-server_02', '/data/var/lib/elasticsearch-server_03' do not match any of the regexes: u'^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$'
services.es01.ports value ['9200:9200', '9200:9200'] has non-unique elements
```

Not sure what is the issue here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to declare `volumes:` at the top level for your bind mounts; that leads to the first error.  The second error is that you have the `9200:9200` published port twice.

Comment: thanks @DavidMaze, i understand the declaring ports twice part. Can you please explain  the other error in some more details. Basically, what i need to do to correct it.

Comment: At the bottom of the file is a section that says `volumes:` but names a bunch of host directories.  Delete that entire section.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidMaze, it worked fine for me.